# Web Chatbot that can save location to database

Tags: rest, leaflet, postgis, geojson, chatbot

I am just newbie in chatbot here, so I don't know any programming language that can create chatbot, and I am sorry If I just make you confuse

My question is I want to make a chatbot, anything programming language is welcome, and I will learn it. But the problem is this chatbot can save response from user that has kind of location. I know that the location can be saved in postgis database system. So I want every respon from user can be inserted to database wheter it is mysql or posgresql in server automatically.

From that database I just want to export it become geoJSON format and upload it on cloud. So I can update my online map with specific time

Thank you from your answer

Comment: Postgis is way more powerful tool than is needed for simply storing locations. If you consider further translation of your spatial data into GeoJSON you might consider using mongodb.

Comment: Hei thank for your comment but how I use st_asGeoJSON in php do you know

Comment: `st_asgeojson()` simply returns geometry entry from db in a form of string, compliant to GeoJSON format, so that you can use one at browser end to render that feature

Comment: Oh, okee I will try it